# Adjoint functor of a functor vs its restriction to a full subcategory

Tags: category-theory

Let $F\colon C\to D$ be a functor, $C_0$ a full subcategory of $C$, $F_0\colon C_0\to D$ the restriction of $F$ to $C_0$.

Let $c\in C_0$ and $d\in D$ such that  there is a natural isomorphism $\hom(-, c)\cong \hom(F_0-, d)$. Does it follow that there is a natural isomorphism $\hom(-, c)\cong \hom(F-, d)$?
Or is there a counterexample? If there is a counterexample, can it happen that there is a $c'\not \cong c$ such that $\hom(-, c')\cong \hom(F-, d)$?

(The intuitive question is: if the right adjoint of $F_0$ sends $d$ to some object $c$, does the right adjoint of $F$ has to send $d$ to $c$ too, or can the right adjoint of $F$ send $d$ to some object $c'$ not isomorphic to $c$?)

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be $c_0 \to c_1;$ $D$ be a trivial category with one object $d$; $C_0$ be the trivial category on the object $c_0$. Then $C_0(c_0, c_0) = * = D(d,d).$ However, $C(c_1, c_0) \not\simeq *.$

At the same time, $C(c, c_1) = * = D(d,d)$ for both $c \in C$.

Comment: Thanks! Can it happen that $F_0$ has a right adjoint, while $F$ does not have a right adjoint? Same question with both occurences of the word "right adjoint" replaced by "left adjoint".

Comment: I wonder: in each question I asked if ony replaces "right adjoint" by "left adjoint", does it follow that the answer is "no" too by duality? Or is it the case that one cannot use duality here and has to exhibit new counterexamples?

Comment: I think it's "no by duality".

Comment: Why does that follow from duality? Also, can it happen that F0 has a right adjoint, while F does not have a right adjoint?